# Neo4j plugin missing in Gephi 0.9.1 version

Tags: plugins, neo4j, gephi

I am pretty new to neo4j. In my graph, there are more than 5k nodes and neo4j browser doesnt show all the nodes, as there seems to be a limit and picture is messy as well. 
So i was trying to gephi 0.9 and installed the same. 
But I am unable to find the neo4j database plugin. I checked under 
Tools --> plugins --> available plugins section

Please let me know, if I am missing something here.

[Plugin screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btrcW.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need the Neo4j plugin for Gephi, as you can use [neo4j-shell-tools](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools) instead to do a [GraphML export](https://github.com/jexp/neo4j-shell-tools#graphml-export), and open that in Gephi.

Beware that the option parsing of `export-graphml` is a bit buggy (and I should open an issue about it); if you want to use the `-t` or `-r` flags, they have to be specified before `-o`, like this:

```
export-graphml -r -o out.graphml match ...
```

I also had to add some metadata description to the GraphML file so Gephi finds more data (and I should also open an issue about that, at least for the generic metadata). The beginning of the file looks like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
<graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
```

which I changed to

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<graphml xmlns="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns http://graphml.graphdrawing.org/xmlns/1.0/graphml.xsd">
<key attr.name="label" attr.type="string" for="node" id="labels"/>
<key attr.name="label" attr.type="string" for="edge" id="label"/>
<key attr.name="someProperty" attr.type="boolean" for="node" id="someProperty"/>
<!-- more descriptions of node properties -->
<graph id="G" edgedefault="directed">
```

Comment: hi i dont have much unix expertise, so I am facing few difficulties in this. I downloaded the zip file and unzipped the contents to the lib folder. Now when I am trying to run                                                                                   export-graphml -r -o out.graphml "[MATCH (n:U)-[r:ACCESS]->(p:P) return n,r,p]" .. I am getting an error saying export-graphml command not found. do we need to run this from neo4j shell? I am using neo4j CE 3.3 version. https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/using-neo4j-shell-neo4j-ce-3x/  Is there anything I am missing here.

Comment: i tried to run from neo4j shell as well. getting same error.

Comment: Yes, you have to run that from `neo4j-shell`. You might want to create a new question if you have an issue with it, and detail what's not working (neo4j-shell itself, export-graphml in neo4j-shell, etc.).